# How to add the border for these 2 combo boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to implement border for the below 2 jquery chosen combo boxes like in the below image i want to make the border for the below 2 search boxes
[image]

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
  
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/9Lrh8wqq/ ??

Comment: @Mi-Creativity yes ur right

Comment: @overflowstack9  you can use feildset, it is much better for this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div style="border: medium solid;
max-width: 354px;
padding: 20px;">
  
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
  
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

```css
.sel-div{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:10px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="sel-div">
  
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
  
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
   
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: Please do not suggest edits that do nothing except change the markdown formatting for a link. Your edits are harmful because they make a link to github.com/foo/bar look like a link to github.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is even better

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text">
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
 
</html>
```